# Using Access 2010 database in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am currently accessing a access 2010 database in c# and its unable to open the database as it doesn't seem to have the correct driver when I was using a .mdb this worked, but now since I'm using a .accdb it doesn't seem to want to open the database.  Here's the opening code.  I was wondering if there was anything you could help me with?

```
public void openDatabase(string dbname)
    {
        //dataBaseName = dbname;
        dataBaseName = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=houses.accdb"; //Defines the location of the database and its type.

        connection = new OleDbConnection(dataBaseName); //Creates a new OleDbConnection using the data from dataBase.

        connection.Open(); //Opens the TCP/IP connection.
    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
```

To

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

See also: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007#84

Answer (score 0):

You need the driver for Office 2007 - [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734)

Answer (score 0):

to use the datbase without Access installed on a client you must also Engine2010 Access Database

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

Regards.